# Unit Testing a c# .Net web service by isolating the web services it depends on

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes, shim

I have to unit test C# project that relies on several other web services. While unit testing I do not want to make calls to the services but just return a dummy value. I'm trying to use shim currently but I'm facing issues. The current code creates a client for the external web service and then calls a method

```
CSSFormTransformationClient client = new CSSFormTransformationClient();
MemoryStream stream = client.TransformToPDF(cssRequest);
```

The definition of the CSSFormTransformationClient is generated by the SvcUtil.exe tool and has a method TransformToPDF as follows

```
public System.IO.MemoryStream TransformToPDF(Mycompany.Enterprise.Reporting.ServiceReferences.CssTransformation.TransformRequest transformRequest) 
{
    return base.Channel.TransformToPDF(transformRequest);
}
```

Now I was assuming i could use shim in the following way to mock a return value for transformToPDF

```
ServiceReferences.CssTransformation.Fakes.ShimCSSFormTransformationClient.AllInstances.TransformToPDF = () => { }
```

But it doesn't let me. Someone tell me how do i mock the transformToPDF method?

Thanks.

P.S - This project uses WCF.

Comment: I've added the fake assembly and everything.. just missing the correct way to go about doing this..

Comment: Can you define "Doesn't let me"? Are you getting an error or other message? What exactly is the problem? Also, have you tried Moq?

Comment: @Brandon
_ServiceReferences.CssTransformation.Fakes.ShimCSSFormTransformationClient.AllInstances_
after this it just gives me two options of "equals" and "reference equals". VS underlines it in red if in case i do anything else. I haven't tried mock. Given the little description and the general fit of moq in such services isolation, would suggest that over shims?

Comment: I'd only suggest it because I've personally never used Shims. I assume it's giving you an error because `TransformToPDF` needs to return a memory stream and you're not doing that.

Comment: @Brandon
Wouldn't that depend on what i give within the { } because i'm providing a detour to a call to that method to come to my definition of TransformToPDF. I may or may not return a memory stream in my implementation of `TransformToPDF`. But in my case VS just wouldn't pick up the method after `AllInstances`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment: try this with Moq ([Available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/)).

```
using Moq;
using TransformRequest = Mycompany.Enterprise.Reporting.ServiceReferences.CssTransformation.TransformRequest;

private MemoryStream _toReturn;

public void SetupTest()
{
    this._toReturn = new MemoryStream();    
}
public void TearDownTest()
{
    if (this._toReturn != null)
    {
        this._toReturn.Dispose();
    }
}

public void YourTestMethod()
{
    var client = new Mock<CSSFormTransformationClient>();

    client.Setup(c => c.TransformToPDF(It.IsAny<TransformRequest>())
          .Returns(this._toReturn);

    MemoryStream stream = client.TransformToPDF(cssRequest); //Get cssRequest beforehand... I don't know where it came from.

    //Continue with your test.
}
```